# PHP MongoDb update $in array

Tags: php, mongodb, syntax

From the MongoDB command line I can do

```
db.user.update({userid: {$in: [435707147,88513850,466518582]}},{$unset: {f1 : 1}})
```

Which will remove the variable f1 from all **user** objects in the DB.  How would you translate that to PHP syntax?

I the following runs with no error, but no changes are made to the DB.

```
$db->user->update(array("userid"=>array('$in'=>$ids)), 
    array('$unset'=> array("f1"=>1)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you set `$ids = array(435707147, 88513850, 466518582);` ?

You probably also need to say it with `'multiple'=>true` to update all of them at once:

```
$db->user->update(array("userid"=>array('$in'=>$ids)), 
   array('$unset'=> array("f1"=>true)), 
   array('multiple'=>true));
```

Comment: Should have added that, yes $ids is an array.  I have tried with multiple and without.  Pretty stumped here.

Comment: Try doing a simple find with the `$in` to see if you can get it to work first. I updated my `$unset` array to use `true` instead of `1`--not sure if that will help.

Comment: I was able to the above to work in a controlled script file.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Wes is correct, you will likely want to use `'multiple'=>true`.  If the the $in query alone still doesn't return any results, make sure the elements in `$ids` are integers and not strings (try calling `gettype()` on each element).